# When is mathematical induction "required" for a proof?

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I am reviewing some material I learned many years ago about mathematical induction, and I think I may have learned it incorrectly. I have been under the impression that there is a correct and an incorrect way to do certain proofs. For example, assume I want to prove the trivial statement: "for any $z \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, $2z+2$ is even."

One "proof" that I would have written would just acknowledge that, given arbitrary $z \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, $2z +2 = 2\left(z+1\right)$ is even by definition of even numbers. This seems to make sense, and since $z \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ is arbitrary and the proof doesn't depend on choice of $z$, I would say that the conclusion is proven.

I recall my former teachers disagreeing and insisting I use induction, something like:

1. $2\cdot 1 = 2$ is even, so the statement holds for $1$.
2. Assume $2z + 2$ is even for $z \in \mathbb{Z}_+$...(then show that $2\left(z+1\right) + 2$ is even.)

Why is this? Are both proofs valid? The induction seems to not help much here, but I can see how for some propositions, induction makes proofs simpler.

The reason I am asking this is because the proof of $a^n\cdot a^m = a^{n+m}$ for $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ is often demonstrated by fixing $n$ to be an arbitrary, then performing induction on $m$, and concluding that since it holds for arbitrary $n$ and all $m \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, it holds for all $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}_+$. I don't understand why induction is "required" for the $m$-variable but not for $n$. Why do I need to do induction at all, and not just say that it is obvious that it holds for arbitrary $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}_+$?

### Edit

I should clarify that the rules of exponents example is from Munkres' "Topology", Chapter 1, Section 4, Exercise 6. It is in the section of the book that defines mathematical induction. A hint is provided to prove the formula for fixed $n$ by induction on $m$.

I will also try to be more specific with my question:

1. Is my "even-ness" proof without induction valid? Meaning, if I say "$2z+2 = 2\left(z+1\right)$ is even for any $z\in \mathbb{Z}_+$", have I conclusively proved it? I understand I *could* use induction here, but do I *need* to?
2. If my even-ness proof works, then shouldn't I be able to do the same to prove $a^n \cdot a^m = a^{n+m}$ for $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}$, by simply saying "it is true because it is true for arbitrary fixed $n$ and $m$"? Is the exercise just giving me an excuse to use induction?

Comment: Often it is possible to prove things both with and without induction but it just depends on what you find convenient for that particular proof and on what assumptions you are willing to make (and whether you want to practice). When you're starting out, many "obvious" facts may be difficult to prove but that is generally not a good reason not to know how you would prove it. It's a skill to be able to recognize how everything you consider obvious fits together and how you can construct a proof for it.

Comment: Given this is a vague memory of yours of an argument you didn't understand at the time, it is hard to guess the point. Maybe you hadn't yet proven the distributive law?

Comment: Regarding the exponents and $m_1, n_1$- why not fix $m_1$, do the induction on $n_1$, then say something to the effect, "Without loss of generality, swap $m_1$ and $n_1$, ..." meaning we take $m_2 = n_1$ and $n_2=m_1$, then fix $m_2$, and apply the part already proved in a slightly different context?  This would then apply to any natural number choices for m and n.
Note: This would apply only if we had commutativity for both addition and multiplication.

Comment: In math particularly, geometry there are many things which seem to be obvious.  One of the point of proofs is to know for sure.  About the even proof, some classes would accept 
Sometimes the unstated assumption is "we've been studying induction, so you need to practice induction",  However, if that's the primary reason, I think it should the reason should be listed explicitly.

Comment: @nickalh That idea for the proof makes sense, so you're basically exploiting the "symmetry" of the formula to apply induction twice. That proof makes sense to me since it applies induction throughout.

Your comment about knowing for sure makes sense as well. I suppose my confusion is that if I fixed $n$ and $m$, I would think it would suffice to say something like $a^n\cdot a^m = a\cdot a \ldots a\cdot a = a^{n+m}$ and conclude that I know it for sure. I see what you mean about these possibly being "exercises" for using induction.

Comment: @MaxMeijer Thanks for explaining, I think I understand your point, that things can be proven in different ways depending on the development. But in the case of my proof that "2z+2 is even", it's not that I don't know how I would prove it, it's that I don't know "how much proof" is required to prove it. Would you say my "by definition" proof is sufficient? Or do I need to actually use induction here?

Comment: "Knowing for sure" is a 2-edged sword. You write that for a fixed $n$ and $m$ the expressions $a^n \cdot a^m = a \cdot a \ldots a \cdot a = a^{n+m}$ suffice to let you conclude that you "know it for sure", but I would question that for the special case where $n$ and $m$ are fixed to be $n=84587568745$ and $m=41540734850506$.

Comment: @stuz At the basic level the three dots in $a^n\cdot a^m=a \cdot a \cdots a \cdot a = a^{n+m}$ has no meaning by itself, even for m,n fixed. As you know, induction is used to define any power $a^n$. Often three dots in an expression are an informal way (in a more advanced context) to express an idea without having every time to write down everything rigorously (induction needed here). Sure, $a^{n}=\Pi_{i=1}^{n}a$ can be used but as you know this is defined by induction. If this is an exercise, its solution will involve induction. (deleted answer because intended just a comment )

Comment: For the evenness proof, note that $2z + 2 = 2(z + 1)$ relies on the distributive property of multiplication. Depending on how you have defined the integers, the multiplication (and also addition) operators could be defined inductively in terms of the successor function, so you'd have to use induction to prove the distributive property.

Comment: @stuz Whether 2 * k is even by definition of being even depends on your definition of evenness. You could theoretically have an inductive definition where 0 is defined as even and a number is even if it is exactly 2 from another even number. In that case using induction would make more sense. My guess is you were just using induction here to get practice with using induction. The important thing to understand is that induction is a fundamental axiom, that it lies at the foundation of maths and that it is an important proof technique so you need to be able to apply it.